# Can useMemo be used to find Fibonacci numbers in a React page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

It is taking more than 30 seconds (instead of less than 1 second), so I don't think it is using `useMemo` correctly:

```html
<body>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.4/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        function Fib({n}) {
            const m = Number(n)
            console.log("Fib", m);

            const fib = (n) => {
                if (n <= 1) return n;
                else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
            }
            
            const result = React.useMemo(() => fib(m), [m]);

            return <li key={m}>Fibonacci({m}) is {result}</li>;

        }

        function App() {
            return (
                <ul>
                    { Array.from({length: 41}).map((e,i) => 
                        <Fib key={i} n={i} />
                    )}
                </ul>
            )
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));

    </script>
</body>
```

It seems it actually has to be:

```
const fib = (n) => {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    else return React.useMemo(() => fib(m - 1), [m - 1]) + React.useMemo(() => fib(m - 2), [m - 2]);
}

const result = React.useMemo(() => fib(m), [m]);
```

but `useMemo()` has to be used at the "top level" function. Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it can be done.

```
  const App = () => {
    const [fibs, setFibs] = useState([1, 1])
    useMemo(() => {
      const len = fibs.length
      if (n <= len) return fibs[n - 1]
      const newFib = fibs[n - 2] + fibs[n - 3]
      setFibs([...fibs, newFib])
    }, [n])

    // do whatever to change n
  }
```

The point is that `useMemo` isn't a typical memorization scheme, what it does is more like a specialized for skipping calculation in some renders.

So here if `n` changes, it want to make an amend to the storage `fibs`, which means `fibs` is more like a real memorization storage to save calculation under all conditions.

So the overall saving isn't on the render part, but more on the calculation which I assume it's the part you want to save :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to use `useMemo()` within the recursive `fib()` function, because of the React rules of hook placement (as you mentioned).

If you turn `fib()` into a custom hook React's rules can be satisfied, but it blew up the stack - at which point I gave it away.
Essentially there's a conflict between the expression to end the recursion `if (n <= 1)` and the React rule that says that hooks must not be called conditionally.

If you move `fib()` outside of the Fib component, you cut the time in half (rough counting). This is because the function isn't re-created on each call,

Using [underscore's memoize](https://underscorejs.org/#memoize) gets timing close to where you expected.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js" integrity="sha256-G7A4JrJjJlFqP0yamznwPjAApIKPkadeHfyIwiaa9e0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.4/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.4/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

      const fib = _.memoize(function(n) {
        return (n <= 1) ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
      });

      function Fib({n}) {
        const result = React.useMemo(() => fib(n), [n]);
        return (
          <li key={n}>Fibonacci({n}) is {result}</li>
        )
      }

      function App() {
        return (
          <ul>
            { Array.from({length: 41}).map((e,i) => 
              <Fib key={i} n={i} />
            )}
          </ul>
        )
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `useMemo` memorizes just _single_ result per _each_ component. It's nothing like global memoization "okay, we already calculated result for 5th, 6th and 7th members in sequence", so even with custom hook it will still be very sloooooooow

Comment: It is possible to use more than one `useMemo()` in a custom hook. The idea would be to cache the n-1 and n-2 calls. However the hook usage rules prevent `fib()` from being converted to `useFib()`.